# What is the easiest way to select all photos from a certain time period in iOS?

Tags: ios, photos

I'd like to select all pictures, say from 2022, or Dec 2022, and AirDrop them to my Mac. I know I can filter them by year and month, but selecting all is kind of a pain (even with the dragging-horizontally-and-then-vertically gesture). Maybe there is a more straight-forward way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

Open Photos app
Tap on "Albums"
Scroll down and select the "All Photos" album.
Tap on "Select" button at top right corner
Tap and hold on first photo in the time period you want select.
Without releasing finger, swipe up or down to continue selecting all photos in that period.
Release the clutch when you've selected all the photos.
You can now deleting or sharing them

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I was referring to as "dragging-horizontally-and-then-vertically". But it takes a while to select sometimes up to a thousand pictures so I was hoping for something I can just click.